# populate form fields php wordpress

Tags: php, forms

I have always stumbled across questions posed on this website when I have been trying to tailor my website, so i'm diving in with my own since I don’t see this particular question asked.

I have a wordpress theme for real estate that I’m attempting to customise, the author is quite good but when it comes to editing code they refuse any support.  I have had some degree of success trial and error but this next bit has me stuck.

On my calendar page you select 2 dates, a check-in day and a check-out day, that then brings up another page to input the price per night etc. 
The thing is that popup box does not pre-populate with the minimum days booking or the check-in day (both of these could be answered from the selected days range which prompted the pop-up).

Pictures are at the end of the post.

So I would like the drop down menu for "allow bookings starting with the check in on changover days" automatically use the first day in the range (3/2/2020 a monday).  And the "minimum days of booking" to automatically populated by using the dates range between the "start date" and "end date".

I believe I need to work with the following areas of my page.

```
<label for="start_date_owner_book"><?php esc_html_e('Start Date','wprentals');?></label>
<input type="text" id="start_date_owner_book" size="40" name="booking_from_date" class="form-control" value="">

<label for="end_date_owner_book"><?php  esc_html_e('End Date','wprentals');?></label>
<input type="text" id="end_date_owner_book" size="40" name="booking_to_date" class="form-control" value="">

<label for="period_min_days_booking"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Minimum days of booking','wprentals');?></label>
<input type="text" id="period_min_days_booking" size="40" name="period_min_days_booking" class="form-control" value="">

<label for="period_checkin_change_over"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Allow only bookings starting with the check in on changeover days','wprentals');?></label>
<select id="period_checkin_change_over" name="period_checkin_change_over" class="select-submit2">
<?php 
    foreach($week_days as $key=>$value){
        print '   <option value="'.esc_attr($key).'">'.esc_html($value).'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Is this something we can automate? Do you feel I need to pay for an expert and have anyone to suggest please?

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: call ajax function upon changing the start and end dates inputs

Comment: Thank you I will see what that involves.

Comment: is there a working example, also hw/where would it pull the calendar days in the booking start day example?

Comment: You can get values using jQuery